# Switching view controllers like Apple Mail paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a view similar to the Apple Mail app message view, where you can tap on the down / up arrows to go to the next or previous view controller.

I've already used UIPageViewController, but that causes conflicts with other gestures in the view.

It looks like they actually recycle the view, since only the data changes.
Is that the best way to do this, or is there a way to "switch" view controllers?

Comment: You have this tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: As mentioned, I don't want to use UIPageViewController because of its gesture recognizers.

Comment: How about create a scrollView and only implementing the dots (UIPageControl)?

Comment: I think this could be what you're looking for: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/